# How to get values just created from NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have these classes:

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


public class Friend: NSManagedObject {

}
```

and

```
import Foundation
import CoreData


extension Friend {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Friend> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Friend>(entityName: "Friend")
    }

    @NSManaged public var profileImageName: String?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var messages: NSSet?

}

// MARK: Generated accessors for messages
extension Friend {

    @objc(addMessagesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToMessages(_ value: Message)

    @objc(removeMessagesObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromMessages(_ value: Message)

    @objc(addMessages:)
    @NSManaged public func addToMessages(_ values: NSSet)

    @objc(removeMessages:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromMessages(_ values: NSSet)

}
```

and

```
import UIKit
import CoreData


extension FriendsController {
    
    func setupData(){

        let context = AppDelegate().context
        
        let mark = Friend(context: context)
        mark.name = "mark"
        mark.profileImageName = "zuck"
        
        let message1 = Message(context: context)
        message1.text = "Hello, my name is mark, nice to meet you"
        message1.date = Date()
        message1.friend = mark
        
        let steve = Friend(context: context)
        steve.name = "steve"
        steve.profileImageName = "steve"
        
        let message2 = Message(context: context)
        message2.text = "Hello, my name is steve"
        message2.date = Date()
        message2.friend = steve
        
        messages = [message1, message2]
    }
}
```

and later, I'm trying to access 'message?.friend?.name', but it's always nil...

```
   class  MessageCell: BaseCell {
        
        var message: Message? {
            didSet {
                nameLabel.text = message?.friend?.name
                if let profileImageName = message?.friend?.profileImageName {
                    profileImageView.image = UIImage(named: profileImageName)
                }
                messageLabel.text = message?.text
                
                if let date = message?.date {
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:m a"
                    
                    timeLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Should I do something else with the context to load these managed objects?
Doesn't make much sense, since I've just create them, just passing as reference to a different class, they should be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
let context = AppDelegate().context
```

This creates *a new instance* of the AppDelegate, it doesn't reference the existing instance.  Since that new instance is created in the `setupData` method, it is deallocated when that method completes.  And because you haven't saved, the data isn't persisted before the method completes.  So the messages array contains NSManagedObjects which no longer have a reference to a valid context, and their values are therefore nil.

You should probably access the existing AppDelegate instance using:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let context = appDelegate.context
```